# Azure Blob Storage - What is the copy speed?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to generate a SAS link to send to other service and this service will use the method CopyFromUrl to copy the file, I want to set the expiration time according to the size of the file but… I can’t find any page in the docs that says what is the speed of the copy operation. Can anyone guide me with this?

Comment: There's really no way to answer this objectively, as speed will vary quite a bit, depending on how the copy is being done, whether the copy takes place within the same Azure region or goes outside the region, etc. You'll need to do some general benchmarking and tailor your expiration accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can Test download speed from Azure Storage Service around the world. by these [AzureSpeed](https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Download) service.

or

you can use these code for check download speed. In my i am using these code for checking 3 file speed. 21mb, 100mb and 675 mb file.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await GetFileAsync("https://myaccount/210mb.pdf?sp=r&st=2022-07-02T10:22:24Z&se=2022-07-03T18:22:24Z&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=zwhyKzuGhuUxxX8PEpgnwFzbhfg4x1UoPzNUvclQQGo%3D", 21);
            await GetFileAsync("https://myaccount/100mb.pdf?sp=r&st=2022-07-02T10:23:24Z&se=2022-07-03T18:23:24Z&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=AFRSJkdgeHeCyAba%2F3vSTwGUvGDj1J%2B8netAvgOsk5U%3D", 100);
            await GetFileAsync("https://myaccount/1gb.pdf?sp=r&st=2022-07-02T10:23:46Z&se=2022-07-03T18:23:46Z&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=cydqUlULOTnY8ruEo2ixSJX6ZQGAbCLnlcKzjLD4KXo%3D", 675);

        }
```

```cs
 static async Task GetFileAsync(string file, int size)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(file))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    var totalBytes = client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize;
                    var receivedBytes = 0;

                    for (; ; )
                    {
                        int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (bytesRead == 0)
                        {
                            await Task.Yield();
                            break;
                        }

                        receivedBytes += bytesRead;

                        int received = unchecked((int)receivedBytes);

                        Console.Write("\r" + received / (1024) + "Kb");
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                    double speeds = receivedBytes/sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(speeds/1024) + " bytes/s, Total Time taken for downloading "+size +" mb size file :- "+ sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds+" Seconds");
                    //var speed = size / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                    //Console.Write("\t[" + Math.Round(speed / 1024, 2) + " MB/s]");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }
            }
        }
```

Output
[image]